# Moving installation location on non rooted Android 5 Lollipop device

Tags: applications, adb, 5.0-lollipop, external-sd, internal-sd

I have a Moto G (2nd generation) with Android 5.02 on it. Internal SD card is about 8Gb and I have an external SD card with 16Gb free space.

Moving application to SDCARD from the application's menu moves it to sdcard0 which is the internal SD card.

Adb shell command:

```
pm get-install-location
```

gives me:

```
0[auto]
```

I tried to set installation location through:

```
pm set-install-location 2
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 2000
```

That is I believe complaining about root permissions.

And because it's a production build trying:

```
adb root
```

gives me:

```
 adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

Is there any way to set the applications install their data to external SD card?

**P.S:** I don't want to install a custom rom or install third party software to root the phone.

**Edit:**
I've noticed that applications data was stored in the folder `/storage/sdcard0/Android`, so I thought of moving this folder to `/storage/sdcard1/` and creating a symlink this way instead:

```
ln -s /storage/sdcard1/Android /storage/sdcard0/Android
```

will this do the job?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically speaking: You can't. At least not *without rooting*.
The main reasons Android does not allow you to install an application to your external SD card are:

1. *Security*: It's the main reason for that restriction. Basic file systems like NTFS or FAT (any version of it) do not allow for Unix-like permission management.
   This means: *any* application would be able to write to *any* file on that storage.
   Thinking of malicious apps, they would be able to replace proper apps with fake/infected ones, bricking your phone and rendering it unusable.
2. *Volatile storage*: Your external SD card is not safe to be inserted in your device all the time. You are able to eject it any time what makes your SD card not a very good candidate for a permanent storage. Consider apps running off of your SD card and you eject it. Those apps will just crash and all other apps saved on your SD card are gone as well. You can't use them at that time and the data of those app is also affected by reason #1.

Comment: I have a linux background so I've considered this approach: I've noticed that the application's menu option "Move to SDCARD" created a folder called Android on sdcard0 (the internal one) with applications data on it; will creating a symlink (in sdcard0) called Android to a folder called Android in sdcard1 work?

Comment: The issue is: Android stores only application **data and obb** in `/sdcard/sdcard0/Android`. Applications are stored in a hidden folder called `.android_secure` where not even `root` has access to (I tested it on my device, you can't  even`cd` to that folder).

Comment: Actually that's precisely what I need! The main problem getting me thinking of this is the **data** especially with heavy games.. The main applications are not that big compared to the data they add later. So you think it might work?

Comment: If it is only *data or obb* then it certainly works. At least on Android versions that do not make `sdcard_rw` belong to the `root` group or feature the user `sdcard_rw` at all. But with a bit of permission changes you should be able to get that sorted out.

Comment: Running `ls -l /storage/sdcard0` gave me this `lrwxrwxrwx root root 2015-04-20 15:59 sdcard0 -> /storage/emulated/legacy` and running `ls -l /storage/sdcard0/` gave me this 
`drwxrwx--x root sdcard_r 2014-12-20 18:16 Android`.. Is that a good or bad news? Since I'm not root I believe I can not set permissions.

Comment: The first result was predictable, your internal SD card is actually located at `/data/media`, where `storage/emulated/legacy` points at. The other result is an "easy fix": First you need to move the original `Android` folder to another location or rename it, to make space for the symlink. Then link `/storage/sdcard1/Android` to `/storage/sdcard0/Android` and name the link `Android`. At last fix all permissions (777). This is just theoretical but I imagine it should work like this.

Comment: I'm testing it right now. `cp -R /storage/sdcard0/Android /storage/sdcard1/` (too shaky about the `mv` lol) then `rm -r /storage/sdcard0/Android` then `ln -s /storage/sdcard1/Android /storage/sdcard0/Android`. If this works the credit goes to you so you may update your answer. I'll let you know! ;-)

Comment: Don't remove `Android` it will break all running apps (or at least most of them). It's just a theoretical approach off of my head; nothing to exactly follow. If you are quick enough, you may be able to recover apps after crashing but keep in mind that all actions are undone after the next reboot.

Comment: Yep! It all broke up! lol I was unable to create a symlink: it gave me the error `ln: /storage/sdcard0/Android: Operation not permitted`. So the next question is how to create a symlink? (I reverted my changes and all is fine.. or so I think for now! lol)

Comment: The main issue is: Android tracks file accesses and if *one* of the `Android` folders are missing, it recreates them a moment later. this is also why applications like Link2SD link individual app's folders instead of the whole `Android` folder. You can try that, but I can't promise success.

Comment: This is quite interesting because I have a problem with only a data folder of a game (that is taking 2Gb).. I will try that and report back. Thank you.
P.S: Link2SD did nothing in my case.

Comment: It's just how Link2SD worked last time I used it. I don't need it anymore because my storage space is sufficient :)

Comment: I failed to create a single symlink. (`Operation not permitted`). I believe it's simply because my `sdcard1` is fat32 formatted. To what should I format it (I mean its main partition)?

Comment: You can create a symlink to anywhere, the destination does not matter (even though `fuse` might not permit you to create a symlink to your external SD card). If you can, try formatting your SD card as `ext4` so permissions can be applied without using `fuse` as an intermediate permission manager, that blocks most read and write attempts without proper package permission.

Comment: I was unable to use ext4 since my phone didn't recognize it and kept w95 fat32 LBA (kernel issue?!).. I was unable too to create symlinks for many reasons: non root (?!), fat32 issue.. Now I believe I'll take option B.. ^^

Comment: Only `root` can create symlinks. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 6):

Basically you can! ;)

- First, **Root your phone!**
- Second, Create a secondary partition in your SD card (Ext.4) >= 2GB and set it as primary.
- Third, download and install Link2sd app from playstore. 
  Open the app, and I will ask you to create a mount point to your 2nd partition. Select Yes. Reboot.

**After reboot, EVERY app you install will automatically go to SD card.**

*If you don't know how to create partition search for a guide in Google there are plenty of them*

Comment: That's actually what's I'm trying to avoid: installing third party software. :-)

Answer (score 4):

That was quite a journey searching for an answer not involving rooting but I ended up:

1. [Unlocking my bootloader](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-a)
2. Booting on [TWRP](http://twrp.me/devices/motorolamotog2014.html) without installing it:

   ```
   fastboot boot recovery.img
   ```
3. Installing [Chainfire's SuperSU](http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu) with TWRP.
4. From [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) or [adb](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)'s shell:

   ```
   su
   pm set-install-location 2
   ```
5. From an application's menu in `Settings > Applications` just pushing `Move to SDCARD` moves it* - its data and obb - to the external SDCARD.
6. Removing SuperSU......

[image: Full unroot]

Nah... I didn't do that! 3:)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this address
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html#shellcommands

Android 5 and above does not support this `pm get-install-location`

Try to backup your apk and follow the steps bellow

```
adb shell pm install -r -s <path of your apk>
```

Example

```
adb shell pm install -r -s /storage/sdcard1/base.apk
```

-r means reinstall apk with existing data and
-s means sdcard

Comment: "*Android 5 and above does not support this pm get-install-location*" -- how do you know? Try this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r29/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java#1819. It is for Android 5.1.1. I have support for this argument in my Android 5.0.2, 5.1.1 and 6.0.1!

Comment: Sorry, but `-s` is for [specifying which device should adb operate on](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#shellcommands) ("`-s <serialNumber>`").

Answer (score -1):

First install Adbd insecure ([apk download from xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3008527&d=1415633566)).

Once installed on your device, open it and mark the box: "Enable insecure adbd".

Now you can change the location to install your apps.