# Which root method is safe and can be unrooted easily safely without aftermarks

Tags: rooting, unrooting, magisk, supersu, kingo

**Question Which root method is safe and can be unrooted easily safely without aftermarks**

I want to root my mobile lyf water 7 and change modify  settings of PM set install location  and if it works then I will like to unroot and install

[Moving installation location on non rooted Android 5 Lollipop device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106028/moving-installation-location-on-non-rooted-android-5-lollipop-device)

I googled founded three methods

1. Twrp installing  and installing super user
2. Installing magisk which writes on Bot  partition and don't touches the system partition
3. Installing kingoroot or one root
4. Xda rooting batch file

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/lyf-water-7-ly5504.3524381/

Which of the above rooting methods are safe to install what are pros nd cins of each methods and which  and can be unistalled easily and don't leave any after marks after unrooting

How to unroot with all four methods

1. Superuser
2. Magisk
3. Kingoroot or one touch root
4. Xda batch dile

Comment: [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217157/218526)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the root file different if a custom rom is installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228253/is-the-root-file-different-if-a-custom-rom-is-installed)

Comment: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#uninstallation

Comment: go with Magisk it is safe and maintained. Note for Android 4 Magisk v22 is required. Magisk v23 only support Android 5+

Comment: btw no need to unroot, you can set *Automatic Response Deny* and withdraw all root permissions, that has similar impact than unroot